# Vstest.console.exe exits with code 255 in Bamboo

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, bamboo

We are running automated unit tests in our Bamboo build, but they are *sometimes* failing even though our log indicates that all tests are appropriately passing.  I've done some Googling and am currently getting no where.  Does anyone have a clue as to why the VSTest.Console.Exe is returning a value other than 0?

Thanks a ton!

Here are the last few lines of the log:

```
build   26-May-2016 14:11:25    Passed   ReInitializeConnection
build   26-May-2016 14:11:25    Passed   UserIdentifier_CRUD
build   26-May-2016 14:11:25    Results File: D:\build-dir\AVENTURA-T2-COREUNITTESTS\TestResults\bamboo_svc_BUILDP02 2016-05-26 14_10_58.trx
build   26-May-2016 14:11:25    
build   26-May-2016 14:11:25    Total tests: 159. Passed: 159. Failed: 0. Skipped: 0.
build   26-May-2016 14:11:25    Test Run Successful.
build   26-May-2016 14:11:25    Test execution time: 27.3562 Seconds
simple  26-May-2016 14:11:32    Failing task since return code of [C:\Program Files\Bamboo\temp\AVENTURA-T2-COREUNITTESTS-345-ScriptBuildTask-2971562088758505573.bat] was 255 while expected 0
simple  26-May-2016 14:11:32    Finished task 'Run vstest.console.exe' with result: Failed
```

Comment: I have this same error (running under Jenkins however). When it happens, the TRX output isn't generated even though the tests pass. This makes it less than useful for tracking test results. I'm still attempting to track the reason for the error.

Comment: @JT. Definitely update me if you ever figure this out.  My current solution is super shaky because I'm basically just ignoring the error generated by the test console, which will undoubtedly bite me in the ass someday!

Comment: .@jhammond see my answer below for the details of what we had to do to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't the solution I wanted but it does keep my build from failing if the return code is something other than 0 and all the tests are passing.  At the end of our test command I add:

```
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
   echo Failure Reason Given is %errorlevel%
   exit /b 0
)
```

All this does it catch the error coming out of the vstest.console.exe and throw a return code of 0 out instead of 255.  If anyone ever figures this out, I would *greatly* appreciate knowing why the return code is something other than 0.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in a comment to the question, I've come up against the issue in the test automation for my company too.

In our case, `vstest` would return 1 when tests failed, but then occasionally return 255. In the case of the 255 return, the test TRX output would not be generated.

In our situation, we are running integration tests that spawn child processes. The child processes have output handlers attached that write to the test context. The test starts the process, then uses the `WaitForExit(int milliseconds)` method to wait for it to complete.

The output handlers on the process output are then executing in a different thread, but have a reference to the test context to write their output.

This can cause issues in two ways:

1. In the documentation for `WaitForExit(int milliseconds)` on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty0d8k56(v=vs.110).aspx), it states:

   > When standard output has been redirected to asynchronous event handlers, it is possible that output processing will not have completed when this method returns. To ensure that asynchronous event handling has been completed, call the WaitForExit() overload that takes no parameter after receiving a true from this overload.

   This means that it's possible that the output handlers are writing to the context after the test is complete.
2. When the timeout expires, the process continues to run in the background, and therefore might also be able to write to the test context.

The fix in our case was threefold:

1. After the call to `WaitForExit(int)`, either kill the process (timeout) or call `WaitForExit()` again (non-timeout).
2. Deregister the output event handlers from the process object
3. Dispose the `Process` object properly (with `using`).

The specifics of your case might be different to ours, but look for threaded tests where (a) the thread might execute after the test is complete and (b) writes to the test output.